# Use ansible to pull docker image but not run it

Tags: ansible, docker-compose

I'm using ansible. I want to upload a `docker-compose.yml` and pull its images, *but not start them*.

I tried this, but it also starts the images:

```
- name: dc
  docker_compose:
    project_src: /srv/foo/
    state: present
    pull: true
    stopped: true
```

I only want to pull - the same as if I use `docker-compose pull`.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently [unsupported](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/31924).

Workaround:

```
- shell: "docker-compose pull"
  args:
    chdir: /path/to/docker-compose-yml/
  changed_when: "'... pull complete' in result.stderr | default('')"
```